# Why did I just lose 100+ rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

At first I thought someone had serial downvoted me and the system was restoring my rep, but on closer inspection it looks like the opposite may have happen, I just don't understand why. :(

And yes, I've read the *learn more* link.

Comment: It seems to relate to user [Thirsty-Kitty](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56501/thirsty-kitty?tab=reputation). You unaccepted two of their answers ([1](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109806/what-are-the-lyrics-and-translation-for-the-nazg%C3%BBl-theme-music/109808#109808), [2](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125449/does-harry-potter-know-about-harry-potter-world/125464#125464)). They then unaccepted two of your answers. This seems to have triggered some sort of voting reversal as they then also lost 90 rep.

Comment: @Valorum but _I_ didn't unaccept, the system did that. :(

Comment: @Valorum if you're asking about user _Thirsty-Kitty_, she's my wife. We're both scifi/fantasy fans and often we both use the same computer. Sometimes our discussions will give one of us an idea for a question/answer, and then the other might end up upvoting it but that's just coincidence - we just have similar interests. It doesn't seem fair to either of us for her voting to be reversed just because we have similar interests and use the same computer. :(

Comment: The [canonical page on sockpuppeting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/278659) from main meta.

Comment: @RedCaio Don't worry too much about it. Like it says on the help page, serial voting isn't necessarily a malicious or abusive thing: it can happen for all sorts of reasons, which the system can't always distinguish between. The rep reversal isn't intended to be any kind of punishment.

Comment: Btw, @RedCaio, I apologise if my answer below sounded brusque or patronising. I wasn't trying to dismiss your concern here, but rather to make clear that this rep loss was a "by design" thing and not something you need to get too worried about. I wanted to close the issue quickly before people started speculating and accusing you of sockpuppetry (I've already had to delete one or two less-than-polite comments from this question), but it probably ended up coming out the wrong way. Sorry.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think this is the nicest anyone's been to me on SE in a while. *wipes away a tear* Thanks :)

Comment: I would have assumed it was a bounty given by someone who got deleted. Then again, if you have 17 thousand rep, I wouldn't really worry about losing 100.

Comment: Better yet - I found a decent answer of yours, and when I can I'll award you the +100 bounty I started. So I'll give you 100 of my own rep... because I love you. I mean, this community. Besides, anyone who has a wife named "Thirsty Kitty" deserves props. Problem solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your [latest comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10599/why-did-i-just-lose-100-rep?noredirect=1#comment32006_10599) seems to answer this. Your physical proximity to another user (and their consistent attention to your questions and answers) seems to have triggered some sort of anti-sockpuppeting mechanism.

Per Shog9's post on the subject of [sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685)

> *What you think is a sockpuppet could in fact be my good friend Nog
>   Shine, who loves everything I write, copies my writing style, **and uses
>   my computer to vote and post stuff when I step away for coffee.***
>
> *But in practice, there are patterns that are extremely unusual unless
>   someone is using a second account. If it actually is a very
>   enthusiastic friend, they should know better than to continue this
>   behavior after being warned about it. Feel free to contact the SE team
>   if you're unsure - we have a fair bit of experience in dealing with
>   this sort of thing.*

If you intend to continue operating two accounts from the same IP address, you'd be well advised to use the [contact us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link to explain your connection to the CMs and make it explicit that your actions are benign. They may (or may not) reverse the reversal but at the very least they'll offer some advice regarding the best way to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: So... if she upvotes more stuff from _other_ users etc. is there a chance at us getting our rep back?

Comment: @RedCaio - Ask a CM using the Contact Us link. They're the only people who can adjudicate. My guess is that they will, but don't quote me on that

Answer (score 6):

As you can see, the majority comes from voting reversals where the system determined that there was voting abuse and reverse the upvotes. Serial voting can happen up or down.

In this case, it's because the system determined your accounts were sock puppets. [While having a spouse or coworker upvote your posts is fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175374/what-is-the-procedure-for-having-my-spouse-significant-other-as-a-member-of-the/175376), you'll need to be more careful in that you're not upvoting/accepting their content in an unusual way (such as accidentally voting for them more often than others, which can happen easily when some in-person mentions a question you're both interested in). And the same is true of them.

The other account, Thirsty-Kitty, has very low activity. Because of this, their activity related to your account probably comprised too large of a portion of their actions, triggering the sock puppet reversals.